# Using active model serializers for json and csv in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, csv, serialization

I'm using active model serializers in my rails app for json, which is working great. Now I also need to export that data as csv and have had to rewrite all of the methods in the serializer for the csv method.

Is there anyway to take the serialized json and convert it to csv? Or a way to share code easily between the model and serializer?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it - but there is the [as_csv gem](https://github.com/danielfone/as_csv).

> Behind the scenes, any classes that include ActiveModel::Serialization will expose their attributes with to_csv.

Comment: Thanks! Not quite what I need though... I think. That seems to be for a custom serialization setup, not active model serializers. But maybe I can just setup something using that instead of active model serializers? But then I'd lose AMS magic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just for others searching, [this is now part of ActiveModel](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cloudxls-rails/0.5.0/ActiveModel/Serializers/CSV)